# Absolute Galois group of global and local fields

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the absolute Galois group of the rational number field. Given a $p$-adic Galois representation $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}$, it is  common to restrict it to the subgroup $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}_l}$ for various primes $l$. This makes me wondering: why is it an efficient way?

For example, is every element of  $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}$ can be conjugated into $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}_l}$ for some $l$? Or is the closed subgroup of $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}$ generated by the union of conjugates of the subgroups $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}_l}$ (for all $l$)  the whole $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finite Galois extensions $K/\Bbb{Q}$ Chebotarev's theorem gives that $$Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})=\bigcup_\mathfrak{p} Gal(K_\mathfrak{p}/\Bbb{Q}_p)$$  so yes it gives that $$Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})=\text{Closure} \langle \bigcup_\mathfrak{p} Gal((\overline{\Bbb{Q}})_\mathfrak{p}/\Bbb{Q}_p\rangle$$